# Syntaxhighlight has no color

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I added the plugin to ckeditor but did not display the color in the code. Help me where is my problem?

[Picture error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UzBix_o_HI-LRs3W5ipbTsStFbyRjvKK)

Comment: you added the plugin by src link or config.js?

Comment: Can you give details?